# Having trouble maintaning persistent column layout (v4.4.1)

Tags: tabulator

I able to move columns as expect and resize them as expected, but on a data reload of the grid or when returning to the page, the Grid reset back to the original layout.

```
var table = new Tabulator("#gvRecords", {
              ajaxURL: document.getElementById('urlAPI').value + "/Properties/Get/",
              selectable: false,
              ajaxParams: { "PropertyID": PropertyID, "Tab": Tab },
              movableColumns: true,
              persistenceMode: "cookie",
              persistenceID: "Properties",
              persistentLayout: true,
```

Any help is appreciated, not sure why I doing wrong, I was able to have this work a while back when testing out Tabulator, but now that I trying to implement, I can't see to get it going.

Comment: Working Demo in js fiddle would help

Comment: Is there a reason you are forcing it to store in cookies, that is mainly there for legacy support, i would recommend not setting the persistenceMode and letting Tabulator decide which is best